# Display screen saver when there is Inactivity in a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitapgesturerecognizer

My app requires to display a screen saver after 2 min of inactivity in a viewcontroller. I have used timer with tap gesturerecognizer to achieve it and it works, but images doesnt scroll. It displays only a single image.

```
NSUInteger pg = 0;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
        timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120 target:self selector:@selector(displayAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self 
        action:@selector(resetTimer:)];
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        tap1.delegate=self;
        tap1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap1];

} 
-(void)resetTimer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [timer invalidate];

}
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    [pageControl removeFromSuperview];
    [ScrollImages removeFromSuperview];
    timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120 target:self selector:@selector(displayAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    return YES;
}
-(void)displayAlert
{ 
    //Display Screensaver images in a scrollview using pagecontrol

   ScrollImages=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
    ScrollImages.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    ScrollImages.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    
    ScrollImages.delegate = self;
    ScrollImages.scrollEnabled = YES;
    ScrollImages.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:ScrollImages];
    int xOffset = 0;
    if(xOffset>=0){
        
        ScrollImages.frame=CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        ScrollImages.scrollEnabled=true;
        [ScrollImages setPagingEnabled:true];
        
        
        for (int i=0; i< [arrScreenSaverImages count]; i++){
           UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*i,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            NSURL *url = arrImages[i];
            NSLog(@"%@", url);
            
           NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
            
            [img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] placeholderImage:nil  options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
            
          ScrollImages.contentSize = CGSizeMake(ScrollImages.frame.size.width*[arrScreenSaverImages count],350);
            [ScrollImages addSubview:img];
            
            
        }
     
        pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
        pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, ScrollImages.frame.origin.y+ScrollImages.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 30);
       
        pageControl.numberOfPages = [arrImages count];
        pageControl.currentPage = 0;
       [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changepage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        
        if ([pageControl respondsToSelector:@selector(setPageIndicatorTintColor:)]){
            pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        
        [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
    }
    
       CGRect frame = ScrollImages.frame;
       frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pg;
       frame.origin.y = 0;
       [ScrollImages scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
       pg++;
       if (pg == arrScreenSaverImages.count+1){
           pg = 0;
           
       }


    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    int page = ScrollImages.contentOffset.x / ScrollImages.frame.size.width;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

How to make images scroll? Any ideas/suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `ScrollImages` every time the timer triggers!

**Solution:**

```
- (void)displayAlert {
    if (ScrollImages!=nil)
        return
```

Comment: Ur code doesn't display screensaver again if waited for 2 min. It displayed only once.

Comment: I told u where is ur bug bro. Now you have another problem in ur implementation.